# Separate items in list with a comma in R

Tags: r, list

I'm trying to separate each of the values in a list with a comma. For example, instead of 'item1''item2', I am looking for 'item1','item2'.

Here is what I am working with:

```
combos <- lapply(2:4, function(x) combn(c("item1","item2","item3","item4"), x, simplify = FALSE))
combos <- unlist(combos, recursive = FALSE)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try `lapply(combos, toString)`

Comment: Thank you @akrun! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We loop over the `list` with `lapply` and `paste` with `toString`

```
lapply(combos, toString)
```

Comment: ,@akrun. How would this work with `Map(paste(., collapse = ","), combos)`?

Comment: @TarJae you can use `Map(paste, combos, MoreArgs = list(collapse =","))` or explicitly a lambda expression `Map(function(x) paste(x, collapse=","), combos)`

Comment: Good to now `MoreArgs`. Thanks master!